# Google Analytics SDK in your app

Tags: android, google-analytics

I followed the instructions here:

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v3/

And I implemented the analytics.xml file as:

```
<resources>
 <!--Replace placeholder ID with your tracking ID-->
 <string name="ga_trackingId">UA-XXXX-Y</string>

 <!--Enable automatic activity tracking-->
 <bool name="ga_autoActivityTracking">true</bool>

 <!--Enable automatic exception tracking-->
 <bool name="ga_reportUncaughtExceptions">true</bool>
</resources>
```

In the end it says "Important: Do not encode dashes in the ga_trackingId string. Doing so will prevent you from seeing any data in your reports."

Does that mean I should leave out the dashes and put something like UAXXXXY? In all other examples, I saw online, people used dashes? Clarification please

Answer (score 1):

No, it means that you can just leave it be like it looks.

```
<string name="ga_trackingId">UA-XXXX-Y</string>
```

The reminder is because Android Lint may prompt you to use encoded dashes instead of "-". You can simply ignore it.

Answer (score 0):

Your lint checker may warn you about the use of the figure dash ('-') in your tracking ID. You can suppress that warning by adding additional attributes to your  tag.

Add this : `<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:ignore="TypographyDashes">`

Hope this helps.